# How do I install Aspell package/library in Windows?

Tags: r, libraries, spell-checking, aspell, hunspell

I would like to install Aspell package in R in Windows but there is no binary file available of Aspell package.

Please suggest some way around.

Following is the message i get on trying to install it.

```
> install.packages("Aspell", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
  Installing package into ‘C:/Users/admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
  (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  package ‘Aspell’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning message:
package ‘Aspell’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is said: "There is currently no binary version for Windows. Send mail to me if you would like one."

From

http://www.omegahat.org/Aspell/